# keras thread safe generator for model.fit_generator with Python 3.6.x

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, keras, generator

I'm using Keras 2.0.8 for U-net 2D medical segmentation project.
Currently I'm struggling to create custom thread safe image generator (for X and y simultaneously). X and y are 4D matrix, with shape n_img x n_col x n_row x T, where T for X is 4, and for y is 1 (4 numerical labels are transformed into one hot encoding in 4th dimension)

Here is my code:

```
def gen_tr(X,y,batch_size):
    n=np.floor((len(X)-1)/batch_size).astype(int)
    s=list(X.shape)
    s[0]=batch_size
    while 1:
        for i in range(n):
            j=0
            X_b=np.zeros(s,dtype=np.float32)
            y_b=np.zeros(s,dtype=int)
            while j<batch_size:
                data=distort_imgs(X[i*batch_size+j,:,:,0, np.newaxis],
                              X[i*batch_size+j,:,:,1, np.newaxis], 
                              X[i*batch_size+j,:,:,2, np.newaxis],
                              X[i*batch_size+j,:,:,3, np.newaxis], 
                              y[i*batch_size+j,:,:,0, np.newaxis])
                X_i=np.concatenate(data[:4],axis=2)
                y_i=data[-1]
                y_i=np.concatenate((y_i==0,y_i==1,y_i==2,y_i==4),
                               axis=2).astype(int)
                X_b[j]=X_i
                y_b[j]=y_i
                j+=1
            yield (X_b,y_b)
batch_size=20
gen = gen_tr(X_train,Y_train,batch_size)
steps=np.floor((len(X_train)-1)/batch_size).astype(int)
model.fit_generator(gen,steps_per_epoch=steps, epochs=5, verbose=1, shuffle=True, 
max_queue_size=10,workers=2, use_multiprocessing=False)
```

And error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 568, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(self._generator)
ValueError: generator already executing

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-1a91cea3a91e>", line 7, in <module>
    max_queue_size=10,workers=2, use_multiprocessing=False)

  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2011, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)

StopIteration
```

I've tried solutions from:
[keunwoochoi.wordpress.com](https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/tip-fit_generator-in-keras-how-to-parallelise-correctly/) and [stanford](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-generator-multiprocessing.html) (same).

None of them worked. When I added:

```
import threading
class threadsafe_iter:
def __init__(self, it):
    self.it = it
    self.lock = threading.Lock()
def __iter__(self):
    return self
def __next__(self):
    with self.lock:
        return self.it.next()

def threadsafe_generator(f):
    def g(*a, **kw):
        return threadsafe_iter(f(*a, **kw))
    return g

@threadsafe_generator
#now goes my generator from above
```

I got error:

```
Epoch 1/5
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 568, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(self._generator)
  File "<ipython-input-12-24605a93d655>", line 17, in __next__
    return self.it.next()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-b07830ef87c0>", line 5, in <module>
    max_queue_size=10,workers=2, use_multiprocessing=False)

  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Users\SZ_KOCOT\Anaconda3\envs\cnn1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2011, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)

StopIteration
```

With workers=1 inside fit_generator and everything works fine (provided generator without code from solutions), including next(gen) and gen.__ next__

With 1 thread data generator performance is insufficient, especially that I have multiple cores avaliable...

Can someone can help me with this problem? I'm kind of newbie in python's threading.

Edit:
I have found a solution/workaround. Maybe a little bit too hacky for keras, but it works. Inspired by [zsdonghao](https://github.com/zsdonghao/u-net-brain-tumor/blob/master/model.py). By splitting dataset augmentation in 10 parts of 2750 samples I'm able to prepare data quite quickly and utilize gtx1080 in almost 100%. Also ram usage doesn't exceed ~22GB.
Training of 1 epoch takes about 14-15min, Data prep/aug takes in total 10-12min.
When I compare it to fit_generator with single worker that is more than 3 times decrease

If it may help someone, here is exact code:

```
import tensorlayer as tl
import pandas as pd

batch_size=20
epochs=10
batch_size=20
step_size=2750
steps=np.floor((len(X_train)-1)/step_size).astype(int)
s=list(X_train.shape)
train_all=pd.DataFrame()
eval_all=pd.DataFrame()

#training and evaluation
for i in range(epochs):
    start_time = time.clock()
    print('Epoch: {0:02d}'.format(i+1))
    for j in range(steps):
        ind=range(step_size*j,step_size*(j+1))
        data = tl.prepro.threading_data([_ for _ in zip(X_train[ind,:,:,0, np.newaxis],
                                                        X_train[ind,:,:,1, np.newaxis], 
                                                        X_train[ind,:,:,2, np.newaxis],
                                                        X_train[ind,:,:,3, np.newaxis],
                                                        y_train[ind])],fn=distort_imgs,thread_count=None)
        X_s = data[:,0:4,:,:,:]                                                 
        y_s = data[:,4,:,:,:]
        X_s = X_s.transpose((0,2,3,1,4))
        X_s.shape = (step_size, s[1], s[2], s[3])
        y_s=np.concatenate((y_s==0,y_s==1,y_s==2,y_s==4),
                                           axis=3).astype(int)
        train=model.fit(X_s, y_s,class_weight=weights, verbose=0,
                        batch_size=batch_size, epochs=i+2,initial_epoch=i+1)
        train.history['epoch']=i+1
        train.history['step']=j+1
        train=pd.DataFrame(train.history)
        train_all=pd.concat([train_all,train],ignore_index=True)
        print(train.to_string(index=False))
    eval=model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    eval=pd.DataFrame({'val_dice_coe':eval[0],'val_dice_hard_coe':eval[1], 'val_iou_coe':eval[2], 'val_loss':eval[3]},index=[0])
    eval['epoch']=i+1
    eval_all=pd.concat([eval_all,eval],ignore_index=True)
    print(eval.to_string(index=False))
    model.save('{0}_ep_{1}.h5'.format(model_name,i+1))
    print('Epoch {0:02d} took: {1:.3f} min'.format(i+1,(time.clock()-start_time)/60))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, you should use `next(self.it)` instead of `self.it.next()`.

You could also try using [Keras Sequences](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence), it seems safer, since it's indexed to preserve the correct order of data when multiprocessing.

Finally, it seems that `workers` affect only the generator itself, not the model. In my tests (I'm not good in threading either...) the only difference I could see with more workers was a bigger queue of preloaded data waiting for their turn into the model.

Comment: Thanks, if I remember well, I've tested next(self.it) too, but it didn't worked. I've came with other solution, training on random 10000 of ~27k train samples.
Will post code later, when It will be tested.

Comment: You problem Exception in thread Thread-10:  is because you not use Keras Sequences which is thread-safe, that's why you got such error